# pass an undefined method call to an attribute containing a different object

Tags: python, class, oop, delegates, pandas

I have a class with an attribute that will be a pandas DataFrame().  I'd like to set up the class such that if any DataFrame() method is called on it, that method will be applied to the DataFrame().

I have set up this scenario already:

```
import pandas as pd
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.name = 'Charlie'

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def head(n=5):
        return self.df.head(n)
```

So I can do this:

```
a = A()
a.get_name()
```

Out[1]:  'Charlie'

```
a.head()
```

Out[2]: Empty DataFrame()

I don't want to redefine each and every method of a class to pass through.  This is just one example.  I'd like to apply this elsewhere.

Thanks,

Pi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the `__getattr__` method of class `A` and [delegate](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-is-delegation) all calls to `self.df` and in case the attribute is not found in `self.df` then look for it in the current object. I don't have Pandas on my system, so I'll define another class for the demo:

```
class B(object):

    def func(self):
        print 'Inside B'

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.df = B()
        self.name = 'Charlie'

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return getattr(self.df, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            #If attribute was not found in self.df, then try in self
            return object.__getattr__(self, attr)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.func()
Inside B
>>> a.get_name()
'Charlie'
```

Comment: Thank you Ashwini!  That nailed it.

Comment: @NauticalMile Builtin class all new-style classes inherit from.